# Denjoy's probability argument for the Möbius function

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory

How or where could I find the proof of Denjoy's probability argument for the Mertens function

$$ M(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x \mu(n) = O(x^{1/2}+e) $$ with  $e \to 0$ based on the fact that the Möbius function $ \mu(n)$ behaves as a random variable that takes the values $\{-1,1\}$ with same probability $\frac12$?

Is there a similar probabilistic interpretation for problems inside number theory?

Comment: I think we're just talking about an application of the Central Limit Theorem here, aren't we? And shouldn't that $+e$ be up in the exponent? And pretty much any problem about primes can be interpreted probabilistically; numbers near $N$ are prime with probability $1/\log N$, probabilistic support for the twin primes conjecture and the Goldbach conjecture, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

An excelent sketch of the proof for Denjoy's argument can be found in [H.M. Edwards' book "Riemann's Zeta Function" page 268](http://books.google.com/books/about/Riemann_s_Zeta_Functions.html?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC).